# Dynamic query in spark.sql

Tags: python, sql, amazon-web-services, airflow

ALTER TABLE tablename SET TBLPROPERTIES ('comment' = ' test load - Loaded with t ${tm_series_dt} on ${curr_timestamp}');

above is my alter statment. am trying to pass in spark.sql as variable.

sql_var1='alter table tablename  set tblproperties ('comment'=' test load  - Loaded `with` tm_series_dt="'+str(demo_tm*seriesdt)+'" curtimestamp= "'+current*timestap+'"')';

spark.sql(sql_var1)

when i add this sql query as variable within single quotes and assign it to a variable. it giving error due to single quotes exisitng inside this query. Please help how to run this in spark.sql

just tried it throwing error

Answer (score 0):

For long strings string I like to format with triple quotes like:

```
table_name = 'my_table'
my_var = f"""
alter table {table_name}
set column=1, column2= 'String value here'
"""
```

Notice the f before for formatting, and then you can pass in variables with {}. If you need to use a { in the string itself, you escape with like {{, but it ultimately looks like just a syntax error here